# Does the name of an interval change if the notes are in different octaves?

Tags: theory, intervals

The interval between C and G is a perfect fifth (P5).

But if the G is in a different octave does the interval name stay the same?

Comment: No. The interval from a C to the G an octave and a half above is a twelfth. If the G is even higher you need to describe it by saying something like "...from the C to the G three and a half octaves higher." 
Of course if the G is BELOW the C it becomes a perfect fourth if it's close, an eleventh if it's in the octave below, and needs to be described if it's even lower.

Comment: I’ve never thought about this, but the question is legitimate: we name the intervals up to 16 but then we add the numbers of octaves.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Any particular reason why that's a comment? That could have been an answer right there. You pretty much answered all parts of OP's question, and then some.

Comment: @user45266 Just modesty! And if I convert it to an answer now it'll mess up the threading. But thanks for your kind words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One concept that I might add is the distinction between *simple* and *compound* intervals.

Simple intervals are intervals of one octave and smaller; compound intervals exceed the span of an octave.

So this C up to G is a fifth. If we move the C down an octave (or the G up an octave), this becomes a twelfth, but we can also call it a "compound fifth," meaning that it's a fifth, but one larger than an octave.

To quickly translate between simple and compound versions of intervals, just remember the "Rule of 7": subtract or add by 7 to move octaves. Thus an 11th is actually just a compound fourth, because 11-7=4.

Comment: Now we're talking. Never heard of that.

Rule of Seven = Modulo 7. 
"In computing, the modulo operation finds the remainder after division of one number by another (called the modulus of the operation)."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: @RandyZeitman Exactly! What we call "diatonic space" is really a mod-7 space, which allows this Rule of 7 to take place. Good catch!

Comment: @Richard   Yep! That is exactly how I describe it in my upcoming video about learning music theory. Keys are a helix and each segment is found by 'inclusive counting, by 5's, in base-7'.

1-2-3-4-5(key! G)
             5-6-7-(8/1)-2 (key! D)
                               2-3-4-5-6 (key! A)

Answer (score 2):

Any interval is the **space** between two notes. For naming, two facts are needed. Names of notes, and number of semitones between them.

So, it stands to reason that the interval name for C>E (M3) will not be the same for C>an E an octave higher.That is M10.

In every case, *half* the interval name stays the same! C> any E will always be **M**, but the number attached will vary.

Answer (score 1):

If C stays in the same place and G goes an octave higher, then yes, names changes. But if bouth of them moves to one side, then they don't change

Comment: Yes, then they wouldn't be in different octaves.

Answer (score 1):

The intervals are counted in the first 2 octaves like this:

1 - Prime

2 - Sekunde

3 - Terz

4 - Quarte

5 - Quinte

6 - Sexte

7 - Septime oder Septe

8 - Oktave

9 - None

10 - Dezime

11 - Undezime

12 - Duodezime

13 - Tredezime oder Terzdezime

14 - Quartdezime

15 - Quintdezime oder Quindezime oder Doppeloktave

Source: German wiki site

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intervall_(Musik)